# Display Pre-ApplyWarning when changing specific properties

Tags: go, terraform

Is it possible to display pre-apply warnings to the user using the Terraform plugin SDK?

For example: Changing the RAM size of a VM resource requires the VM to be shutdown. Therefore I'd like to display a warning to the user that the VM will be restarted during the update. This should happen *before* asking for approval and not after applying the changes.

I tried checking for changes in the resource config in the `ReadContextFunc`, but it didn't do do anything in the :

```golang
func resourceRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    // ...

    if d.hasChanges("foo") {
        diags = append(diags, diag.Diagnostics{
            Severity: diag.Warning,
            Summary: "Changing foo is a crime"
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The plan approval stage of apply *is* the warning users receive regarding what the impact of applying will be.

Comment: The plan/approval stage of apply only shows _what_ is being changed, but I want to display a warning about possible side-effects when a specific property will be changed.

Comment: I think what you tried here is _supposed_ to work, assuming you did eventually return that updated `diags` as your return value. If you're returning a warning and it's not appearing somewhere in the `terraform plan` output then that seems like a bug either in the SDK or in Terraform Core, so it might be worth reporting in [the SDK repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk), where it'll be necessary to follow the call stack up and see which component is failing to propagate the warnings.

Comment: Oh, actually: I don't think `d.hasChanges` is meaningful in the "read" function, because there is no change being planned there -- it's just updating the state to match the remote object. So probably execution is just not reaching that branch at all. You could try doing something like this in the `CustomizeDiff` function instead, since that's called as part of planning when Terraform has both the prior value and the configuration to compare.

Comment: Great thought with `CustomizeDiff`! Unfortunately, `CustomizeDiff` currently only returns an instance of type `error` and not the new `diag.Diagnostics`. Will create a feature request but until then I'll have to wait for the next release I guess...